# Logcat Warning While Installing App on AVD

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

I'm installing my app on an AVD for the first time since I picked up the project from someone who worked on it 3-4 years ago. After running it for the first time, it is installing and I have the logcat report going through. I was wondering if the warnings such as:

```
W/dex2oat: Compilation of void android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList() took 110.042ms
```

where important warnings or things just to inform me. Because usually, information passes through information (I/) am I right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just information.  I usually see things like "main thread may be doing too much..."  Stuff like that.  It's just the emulator complaining that it has a lot to do.  But it's just an emulator after all.  It's a miracle those things run as well as they do.

As long as your app is behaving well on your actual devices, you can ignore stuff like that, for the most part.

Comment: Great thank you! In fact, the emulator is dying so much that I plugged my phone in :P I thought that I left my cable at home (and we don't have any at my job) but I could plug it in! Thanks!